# How do I delete history on MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, history

My user is part of the sysop group, but I do not see a way to edit the history.  I have even added the variable `$wgRCMaxAge = 2592000` to the `LocalSettings.php` file.

Comment: Do you mean "edit the history" as in rewriting it? MediaWiki only supports merge and partial deletion of history, but not history rewriting. (Well, you can rewrite history with XML importupload rights, but that's an abuse of course.)

Comment: @Nemo why would that constitute abuse? If Mediawiki is used, for example, as a personal notebook, it is a perfectly reasonable desire to have*your* system contain the data *you* want to have in it. This includes rewriting history.

Comment: @Nobody-Knows-I-am-a-Dog sure, I was only talking about "rewriting history" in the general sense, which includes attributing edits to *others*: I'm saying you can easily do that with XML imports, but (usually) you shouldn't. But we're probably getting offtopic here, unless we get more information about OP's goals. If you have some specific use case in mind, I'd love to discuss it in its own question!

Comment: @Nemo My other use case is having a clean slate state of an mw installation which after installation gets some initial work and then has its history cleaned up before delivery. I already solved this by a direct edit in the database with phpmyadmin but thnx for the offer. Since history *can* be rewritten by sysop and is not cryptographically protected (as it (s|c)could for audit use cases) I see nothing wrong with rewriting and I usually *expect* it to be rewritten; the ethical mileage may vary, the technical is crypto.

Answer (score 2):

See [RevisionDelete](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:RevisionDelete). [$wgRCMaxAge](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRCMaxAge) controls how long back can you go in Special:RecentChanges, it's not related to anything like that.